# Adding the crypt() library to a C program in Windows 10 cmd prompt

Tags: c, windows, cmd, static-libraries, crypt

I have written a C program 'hashed.c' which requires the use of the crypt() function to carry out the hashing of various words.

I have downloaded the GNU C library from an online source (http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/) which contains the crypt library I need along with a number of other libraries. I have extracted all of the contents of the GNU C library to the same directory that my 'hashed.c' program is located in.

This directory is located in **C:\test\**.

In my program code I have included the header file

> `#include <crypt.h>`:

However when I attempt to compile the program using

> cl DAnew.c

I receive an error message saying:

> Cannot open include file 'crypt.h'. No such file or directory

The crypt.h file is located in C:\test\crypt\ and so I have changed the command line to:

> cl DAnew.c /I C:\test\crypt

to directly link the crypt.h file. However I now receive the error:

> Cannot open include file '**features.h**'. No such file or directory.

The 'features.h' file it is referencing is located within the same directory at:

> C:\test\include\features.h

Would anyone be able to show me how to correctly link the crypt library (as well as the others libraries needed) to my C program please?

I have downloaded the Visual C++ build tools and I am using the 'Visual C++ 2015 X86 Native Build Tools Command Prompt'.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`cl DAnew.c /I C:\test\crypt;c:\test\include`

Your compiler knows where to find it's standard includes but does not know where your custom includes are located.  It must be informed about all of them.

By the way, this is not `linking the crypt library`.  This is `setting the search path for custom include files`  You will have much the same effort when you attempt to `link with the crypt library`.  The above information should be enough to get you started on that path.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I started to add the link the other files that it requested, including the features.h file in the include folder. However now it comes up with an error that there is no such directory for the file 'libio/stdio.h' however I cannot find such a file. I have included the paths for the individual 'stdio.h' and 'libio.h' files using /I but the problem still persists.

Comment: check the documentation for you compiler / you may need to specify in environment variables where your standard include files (and libraries) are located.